# Can I use semi-structured interviews for collecting insights for a prototype?

Tags: interaction-design, user-research, users, interview, requirements

I have a low-fidelity prototype and I would like to use semi-structured interviews to ask users questions while having a walkthrough of the prototype.
Do you think it's a good idea to choose semi-structured interviews or should I rather go with structured interviews?

So currently I am in the phase where I have finished the first version of the prototype and tested it using heuristics evaluation, now I would like to gather more information from users so I can refine the user requirements and consequently the prototype.

**Prototyping -> Heuristics evaluation -> Semi-structured interviews -> Refine requirements -> Re-design prototype**

Comment: Welcome to UX StackExchange. Can you give us a little more clarity around the definition of a "semi-structured interview" vs. a "structured interview"? It sounds like semi-structured is fluid based on the way the user is responding to the prototype, is that accurate?

Comment: Well 'semi-structured' and 'structured' are part of UX glossary and it defines how an interviewer will structure questions in an order or more towards fluidic approach. More detail could be read here https://bit.ly/2QsvAL1

Answer (score 0):

When a prototype is available in hand - its always easy to visualize and phrase questions. Also, the answers can be also premeditated and visualized much ahead in time. Structured interview will allow to show the prototype in sequence and keep things in order. You may have one or two questions emerging spontaneously - but a structured interview is best as it sets lot of home work and orderly. I vouch for it.

Semi-structured will be handy when the subject is little distant to visualize or weave head around.

Answer (score 0):

Since (if I read your process correctly) it seems like it will be the **first time you're getting external feedback** for your prototype, I'd suggest **semi-structured**.

I would argue that getting open feedback (including feedback you weren't expecting) and the chance to explore it deeply is more valuable for you at this stage than being able to compare across respondents.

But since you don't state what you're trying to get from this, it's hard to comment on the best method — can you expand on your goals and expectations?